# Which application binds a keyboard shortcut

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, print-screen

I just found a wonderful keyboard shortcut. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and the mouse cursor will turn into a cross which allows you to mark a rectangle of the screen (by left click-hold, drag, release -- you will see a visual rectangle) and it will save that part of the screen into the copy&paste buffer.

Now, while that is very useful, I can't seem to figure out which program is responsible for this feature. My question is: how do I find which mechanism (software) is catching my keystroke?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two interesting resources for your answer : [Configure custom keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu](http://lifehacker.com/256955/configure-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu) and [Assign Custom Shortcut Keys on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/)

I wonder why you haven't googled it for this question! However, hope this helps and best of luck. Please report here if you find it not useful (better is voting down) or vice versa.

Comment: I did google it but it didn't turn up anything useful. I don't know if you misunderstood my question, or if I misunderstand you. I am not trying to assign a keyboard shortcut. I am trying to figure out which mechanism (software) is catching a specific keystroke. In this case Ctrl+Alt+PrtScr in a pretty standard Ubuntu/Unity setup.

Comment: Please go through the second link to understand properly. Metacity is probably your answer.

Comment: In the `global_keybindings` section for Metacity I find that PrtScr maps to `run_command_screenshot` and Alt+PrtScr maps to `run_command_window_screenshot`, and those commands can be found to use the gnome-screenshot utility within the `keybinding_commands` section. This, unfortunately, does not answer my question.

Comment: In my Google search before posting this question I did find, among other non-solutions, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts. I am familiar with the PrtScr and Alt+PrtScr shortcuts from before.

Comment: Err, in my first comment to your answer I accidentally wrote "Ctrl+Alt+ṔrtScr", it should say "Ctrl+Shift+PrtScr" as in the question. Just so there is no confusion on which key-combo I am talking about here. :)